# Avoiding suicide bullets in Deathsmiles

Tags: deathsmiles

How can I avoid the massive amounts of suicide bullets in the Gorge level in Deathsmiles? I've tried going there using level 1 routes only but I cannot make it through without dying multiple times.

Is there anything I can do to make it through the level without dying?

Comment: Which level was Gorge, again? It's been a while.

Comment: @Grace Note It's the optional level before the final level, Hades Castle.

Comment: ...I was afraid that you meant that one... If you can wait until the weekend, I'll setup the 360 and I'll have another go, see how it is I managed past it.

Comment: FYI, The death mode (suicide bullets) is triggered after 5 stages played in level-3 difficulty

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get better at avoiding suicide bullets is to practice.  The greatest way to do this is to limit yourself to only 1 credit every playthrough, and never hitting continue when you lose all your lives.

If you keep up this strict training regiment, you will soon find yourself getting better and better and making it further in the game without dying.  Soon you will be able to dodge like a pro, and those suicide bullets in the gorge level will no longer be a problem for you.

Also, you might want to try playing through a few stages on level 2 or 3.  If your only playing at level 1 before hitting gorge, the extreme shift in difficulty may be what's tripping you up.

In short, play with more discipline.  You'll be amazed at the results.

Edit:  You can also position your familiar in front of you.  The familiar eats suicide bullets.